# Date time picker accessibility issue. Not read more than one character properly

Tags: angular, nvda

we are using NVDA with angular 11 or 12 for accessibility prime ng date time picker component not read properly for example

while date selection like 11 or 12 using arrow key it read character by character  like(eg. for 12 on pressing arrow key first time it read one and again  pressing arrow key it read two )

Comment: Do you have an example to try?  Hard to give advice without seeing the code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.